# Core 2 not allowing me to add new role in controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller

I have recently started a new web app using Core 2.0.3 and code i have previously used to add new roles, is now giving me a Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.NewRole))
{
    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role.NewRole));
}
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
```

Previous apps i have used the exact same code in we on Core 2.0.2 but surely this isnt the issue at hand here?

role.NewRole is a string for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your DI reference setup and assigned using your object's constructor?

`private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager`

```
public obj(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager) {
    _roleManager = roleManager
}
```